# Meta slider disapears the moment i run this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This snippet of code is messing with my Meta Slider on homepage and I have no idea why. The moment I insert the code my drop down text works but my Meta slider will disappear. When I remove the code the Meta slider works again.

I am running it in a text/HTML wordpress textbox widget and I have the jQuery update plugin enabled. 
issue does not seem to be Jquery as i can remove the -code- and it still removes my Meta Slider.

```
<html>
    <style>
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        ul li a {
            color: blue;
        }
        ul li div {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <ul id="read_more">
            <li>
                <p>Read more</p>
                <div>Death</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#read_more li p').each(function() {
                    $(this).click(function() {
                        $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle(300);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Error in console? Doesn't wordpress removes `$` reference once DOM parsed? Try: `$(function($){/* $ still refer jQuery*/});`

Comment: Yup @A.Wolff is right... or jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //code here });

Comment: found error in console../:472 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: and      jquery.colorbox.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: lightbox_html is not defined

Comment: Will atempt the above comments quick. but seems i may have a '< 'out of place.

Comment: doesnt work... just tested i removed the the <script></script> part completely... so just running the css and html.. still removes my Meta Slider o.O

Comment: Try removing the css code its probably affecting the slider

Comment: i coulda swore i tried that... but yeah was the div display:none... ai i r such an idiot. Thank you #Antonio Smoljjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the styles to all `ul` elements and `li` children elements which also targets meta slider since it uses that same structure

You are probably trying to edit other elements but inadvertengly affecting the slider too.

You can solve this by adding a distinct class to your ul your are trying to edit lets say `<ul class='myNav'>` then the styling can be like this:

```
ul.myNav { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Or

```
.myNav { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
```

Comment: Great stuff man thanks.. pulled out to much hair for this silly thing :)